# flann dependency to matlab - MEX

Tags: c++, matlab, ubuntu, cmake, flann

I faced below error when I tried to install the flann library from the source on the ubuntu machine.

> /flann-master/src [72] mkdir build
>
> /flann-master/src [73] cd build
>
> /flann-master/src/build [74] cmake ..
>
> CMake Warning (dev) at cpp/CMakeLists.txt:3 (add_definitions):
>     Policy CMP0005 is not set: Preprocessor definition values are now escaped
>     automatically.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0005" for policy details.  Use
>     the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
>   This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
>
> CMake Error at cpp/CMakeLists.txt:114 (install):
>     install TARGETS given no LIBRARY DESTINATION for shared library target
>     "flann_cpp".
>
> CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
>     No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as
>
> cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
>
> should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be lower
>     if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For more
>     information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
>   This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
>
> /flann-master/src/build [75]

The solution to this was mentioned in another question. I should be in the root directory (containing bin, src, examples etc) and it solved. And there is another missing part in the documentation that I should run

> make install

As I am sudoer on the remote machine, I need to install it on my home directory. So, I created a new directory outside of the flann (flanninstall) and I tried below command.

> cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/eson/matlab/flanninstall/ ..

I hope it helps me to generate the files in my home directory and I can copy or link them to matlab. 
However, I copy the files from this address to current directory that I am working on my script in matlab. 
I still get below error.

> -> g++-4.4 -c  -I/usr/local/MATLAB/2012a/extern/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/2012a/simulink/include -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -ansi -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread  -DMX_COMPAT_32 -O -DNDEBUG  "nearest_neighbors.cpp"
>
> nearest_neighbors.cpp:35: fatal error: flann/flann.h: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated.
>
> mex: compile of ' "nearest_neighbors.cpp"' failed.
>
> Error using mex (line 206)
>   Unable to complete successfully.

Earlier [@rayryeng](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29131285/2674061) helped me on the MEX setup but when I try to run below command I faced earlier problem.

> mex -v -O nearest_neighbors.cpp

I appreciate your advice.

Comment: You have to execute the root CMakeLists.txt. You're building `/flann-master/src/build [74] cmake ..`, i.e., `src/CMakeLists.txt` so it's wrong. You   must create your build folder into root one and then run it-> `/flann-master/build$ cmake ..`

Comment: Thanks @fenix688, I found that and I mentioned it in the middle of my question. That was the first problem that I had.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that I need to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in linux for my user.
The command will be :

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/eson/alg/matlab/flanninstall/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"

This is different path that normal path that you should add if you have root access or sudo access on your machine. 
That would be something similar to below line:

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Your_build/build/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"

The above path should not be completely right, because it could be something that start with /usr/local/ or /usr/include/ .
If I understand the exact path for general case or others have the complete answer, I will update it.